# Delete elements from vectored stack in C

Tags: c, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, stack

I got task from my teacher to create a stack using abstract data type and subprograms to push and pop elements.
But I have some problems with procedure which I used to delete elements.

```
struct house {
    address N;
    int number_floor;
    int number_flat;
    char wall;
};

struct StackATD  {
    int top;
    house body_stack [size_stack];
    void (*Push)(int size_stack, StackATD*&tmp, house data[]);
    void (*Delete)(StackATD*&tmp, int del);
};


void Delete_element(StackATD*&tmp, int del)
{
    int i;
    for (i = -1; i < del; i++)
    {
        for (i = -1; i < size_stack; i++)
        {
            if (tmp -> top != 0)
            {
                tmp -> body_stack [tmp -> top] = tmp -> body_stack [tmp -> top + 1];
                tmp -> top--;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As a result all elements in stack should be equal to zero. But I cannot write something like that:

```
tmp -> body_stack [tmp -> top] = 0;
```

because variable of created type house cannot be equal to variable of integer type. So all elements except the first one get random values. 
How I can I delete elements from the stack making them being equal to zero?

Comment: Use a different variable name for the inner loop.

Comment: I didn`t understand properly. Do you mean the name of counter in the inner loop?

Comment: Yes. You won't get two nested loops to work, if they are using the same variable `i`. It's like trying to make tea and coffee in the same mug. Call one `j`.

Comment: _How I can I delete elements from the stack making them being equal to zero?_ - You cannot… Presumably you misunderstood the task you got; to get help in understanding it, cite it.